# Netbeans platform command line parsing. Want to lock command prompt until task completed

Tags: java, command-line, netbeans-platform, rxtx

I hope this makes sense:

I have a netbeans platform application that can also be ran from command line using the OptionProcessor class. Currently I execute the application and it instantly seems to be sent to background with the output being split out to command line still.

```
C:\Program Files\myApp\bin>myApp --p="COM9" --c="C:\Users\Vi\Documents\ser.txt" --nogui --nosplash

C:\Program Files\myApp\bin>

The launcher has determined that the parent process has a console and will reuse it for its own console output.
Closing the console will result in termination of the running program.
Use '--console suppress' to suppress console output.
Use '--console new' to create a separate console window.
WARNING:  RXTX Version mismatch
        Jar version = RXTX-2.2pre1
        native lib Version = RXTX-2.2pre2
```

As you can see As soon as I call my EXE Windows automatically gives me the ability to use the command line again. I want to lock the command prompt until the application completes and returns a TRUE/FALSE.

Also I'd love to suppress that warning (only that warning) but that's not critical.

Thanks the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your application is composed of a launcher (native) and a worker (Java).
The launcher blocks the console until it do its job: launching a Java VM.
Launch your application with java -jar xxxx and the console will be blocked until Java terminate.

Comment: Since its a Netbeans Platform Application the file is an installed executable.

Comment: Of course, but what the executable contains? Look at it's execution with a process explorer, I guess a Java VM is launched when it runs.